# How to use async-await in findOneAndUpdate

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

i tried following code to - find a name and replace same with another name in database and count and print the number of documents who have age of 30

```js
const findAndUpdate = async (name, age) => {
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({name})
    const count = await User.countDocuments({age})
    return count
}

findAndUpdate('oldName', 'newName', 30).then(count => {
    console.log(count)
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e)
})
```

Comment: Your function takes two parameters, 'name' and 'age', yet you call it with three parameters...

Comment: HI sir,In database 'name:' old name need to be replace with new one.so which argument should i use??async(name,name,age)  returns error duplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are not providing the newName to the `User.findOneAndUpdate()`. You could fix it like so:

```js
const findAndUpdate = async (oldName, newName, age) => {
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({name: oldName}, {name: newName})
    const count = await User.countDocuments({age})
    return count
}

findAndUpdate('oldName', 'newName', 30).then(count => {
    console.log(count)
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e)
})
```

Comment: Already done showing"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

You are using it fine. Async/await works like this.
You have a function that performs a task but you don't want to wait till it completes the task before it can continue another task.

Then you use the async statement to show it is a asynchronous function then you use the await when you want to perform a task that returns data so that it doesn't block the other tasks.

Comment: showing error                                                                                                             reason: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The expression evaluated to a falsy value:

    assert.ok(!isNaN(val))

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are calling `findAndUpdate` expecting it to return a promise, if you want to use `.then` to get the count your function has to return a promise

```js
const findAndUpdate = (name, age) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(...)
            const count = await User.countDocuments(...)
            resolve(count)
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err)
        }
    })
}
findAndUpdate(...).then(count => {
    console.log(count)
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e)
})
```

Comment: here where i can insert old name and new name for replace

Comment: i'm assuming you are using mongoose?

Comment: Declaring the function async makes it return a promise.